# Where can I find a real representation for 8 dimensional gamma matrices?

Tags: resource-recommendations, spacetime-dimensions, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I understand that gamma matrices can be real in $d = 8$ and with Euclidean signature, with minimal dimension $16\times16$. Does anybody know where I can find such a representation explicitly written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book "Supergravity" of the authors D.Z.Freedman and A. van Proeyen (edition 2012) shows in chapter 3.1.1 the construction of gamma matrices in arbitrary dimensions.

Chapter 3.1.1 is part of Part 1 of the book, which can be read only with the knowledge of relativistic field theory. Anyway, in chapter 1 and 2 there is an introduction into relativistic field theory.
But for Part 1 neither knowledge of Quantum Field Theory is needed nor of General Relativity.
In the more advanced chapters of Part 1 (not necessary for the construction of gamma matrices in D dimensions) the knowledge of Supersymmetry might be helpful. For Part 2 of the book it is also useful to know about General Relativity and Differential Geometry.
But most of the material needed is actually explained in the book.

Part 3, however, is already rather advanced. It shows the construction of different Supergravity theories in different dimensions under different assumptions. I think, the text is self-contained, so if most of the exercises are done Part 3 can be read on the basis of Part 1 & 2.

A draft on the book can be found on the internet.

[http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/~alberto/apuntes/freedman.pdf](http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/%7Ealberto/apuntes/freedman.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Frederic Thomas, page 67 of http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/~alberto/apuntes/freedman.pdf had exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

So I believe you already know that in low dimensions the Clifford algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are given by

$$Cl(0,0)=\mathbb{R}$$

$$Cl(1,0)=\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}\quad Cl(0,1)=\mathbb{C}$$

$$Cl(2,0)=\mathrm{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\quad Cl(1,1)=\mathrm{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\quad Cl(0,2)=\mathbb{H}$$

where $\mathbb{C}$ is the field of complex number and $\mathbb{H}$ is the ring of quaternions, and $\mathrm{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{K})$ stands for the $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{K}$.

Then, one can prove the following identities:

$$Cl(p,q)\otimes Cl(2,0)=Cl(q+2,0)$$

$$Cl(p,q)\otimes Cl(1,1)=Cl(p+1,q+1)$$

$$Cl(p,q)\otimes Cl(0,2)=Cl(q,p+2)$$

From these identities, one finds the table

$p-q$ $\mathrm{mod}$ $8$:

- $0$: $Cl(p,q)=\mathrm{M}_{2^{l}\times 2^{l}}(\mathbb{R})$
- $1$: $Cl(p,q)=\mathrm{M}_{2^{l}\times 2^{l}}(\mathbb{R})\oplus\mathrm{M}_{2^{l}\times 2^{l}}(\mathbb{R})$
- $2$: $Cl(p,q)=\mathrm{M}_{2^{l}\times 2^{l}}(\mathbb{R})$
- $3$: $Cl(p,q)=\mathrm{M}_{2^{l}\times 2^{l}}(\mathbb{C})$
- $4$: $Cl(p,q)=\mathrm{M}_{2^{l-1}\,\,\times 2^{l-1}}\,\,(\mathbb{H})$
- $5$: $Cl(p,q)=\mathrm{M}_{2^{l-1}\,\,\times 2^{l-1}}\,\,(\mathbb{H})\oplus\mathrm{M}_{2^{l-1}\,\,\times 2^{l-1}}\,\,(\mathbb{H})$
- $6$: $Cl(p,q)=\mathrm{M}_{2^{l-1}\,\,\times 2^{l-1}}\,\,(\mathbb{H})$
- $7$: $Cl(p,q)=\mathrm{M}_{2^{l}\times 2^{l}}(\mathbb{C})$

where $l=(p+q)/2=d/2$.

So when you are talking about the Gamma matrices in Euclidean signature, the algebra is really $16\times 16$ real matrices. It has $256$ generators given by

$$E_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix}
\ddots & \vdots & \vdots & & \\
 \cdots 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
 \cdots 0 & 1 & 0  & \cdots \\
 \cdots 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
 & \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix},$$

where the only nonzero entry is at $i$th row and $j$th column.

The identities I have used can be found in any textbooks of Clifford algebra. For example, you can read chapter 22 of [Differential Geometry and Lie Groups for Physicists](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/differential-geometry-and-lie-groups-for-physicists/848DF84177C9CE57F76EF827B14395CC).